# How do you change an IDE-Created JPanel to a Custom-Created JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, jpanel

I want to change a specific JPanel inside my UI.

```
public Tester() {
    this.setSize(800,800);
    this.setContentPane(mainPanel); // A created panel using Intellij IDE
    otherPanel = new MyPanel(); // A custom created panel without the use of Intellij
    changePanelButton.addActionListener(e -> {
        changePanel = otherPanel // Not Working
    });
}
```

I can't use the setContentPane from my JFrame since it will change all of the frame's contents, not just the panel I want to change.

Comment: mainPanel is the main Panel of my Frame which consists of a panel and a button (which is outside the panel)
changePanel is the current name of the panel I want to change.
otherPanel is an instantiated JPanel object that calls MyPanel(), which is the custom-created panel.

Comment: 1) Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556). 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) *"mainPanel is the main Panel .."* [Edit] that info into the question. It will be more noticeable than in a comment.